# Xamarin RectangleF.Contains behaving incorrectly

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, system.drawing

The only difference in these two tests is 84.55808f vs 84.5f in the width of the two inner rectangles.

Yet contains ends up being false while contains2 ends up being true. Wow.

Using the Xamarin.iOS C# (Monotouch) environment and the Xamarin IDE on a Mac

Can anybody verify this? And if so can anybody identify the problem?

Thanks!

```
RectangleF r1 = new RectangleF (119.221f, -122.9433f, 646f, 646f); 
RectangleF r2 = new RectangleF (238.4419f, 0f, 84.55808f, 77.11342f);
bool contains = r1.Contains (r2); 

RectangleF r3 = new RectangleF (119.221f, -122.9433f, 646f, 646f); 
RectangleF r4 = new RectangleF (238.4419f, 0f, 84.5f, 77.11342f); 
bool contains2 = r3.Contains (r4);
```

Comment: Is that `System.Drawing.RectangleF`? In VS 2012 both `contains` and `contains2` are true.

Comment: Explain your environment. By me both return true.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear... this is using the Xamarin.iOS C# environment and the Xamarin IDE on a Mac.

Comment: I confirm this on Xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Intersect(r1,r2)` returns `{{X=238.4419,Y=0,Width=84.55807,Height=77.11342}}`. The `Width` is != `84.55808` and therefore the comparison in `Contains` "Is the intersection rectangle the same as the `rect` argument?" fails.

So ultimately, this comes down to `323 - 238.4419`. If you do that with paper-and-pencil, you'll get `84.5581` but with floating point, `323f - 238.4419f` = `84.55811f` (N.B.: extra 0.00001).

I've submitted this as a bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15518

Answer (score 0):

this is not an answer, but it's too long for a comment.

I can confirm this behavior on Xamarin.iOS. Here's the implementation of `Contains` and other helpful methods:

```cs
public bool Contains (RectangleF rect)
{
    return rect == RectangleF.Intersect (this, rect);
}

public static RectangleF Intersect (RectangleF a, RectangleF b)
{
    if (!a.IntersectsWithInclusive (b))
    {
        return RectangleF.Empty;
    }
    return RectangleF.FromLTRB (Math.Max (a.Left, b.Left), Math.Max (a.Top, b.Top), Math.Min (a.Right, b.Right), Math.Min (a.Bottom, b.Bottom));
}

private bool IntersectsWithInclusive (RectangleF r)
{
    return this.Left <= r.Right && this.Right >= r.Left && this.Top <= r.Bottom && this.Bottom >= r.Top;
}


public static RectangleF FromLTRB (float left, float top, float right, float bottom)
{
    return new RectangleF (left, top, right - left, bottom - top);
}
```

I don't feel like checking the math on Saturday evening...